# call a node.js service in Xamarin Forms

Tags: node.js, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms I want to call a node.js service when the app starts.
In App.xaml.cs I have this:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
      await CheckDeviceRegistered("1231234");
}

private async Task<bool> CheckDeviceRegistered(string id)
{
     try
     {
         return await _deviceService.GetDevice(id);
     }
         catch (Exception e)
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

which calls this:

```
public class DeviceRegisteredService : IDeviceRegisteredService
    {
        #region IDeviceRegistered
        public async Task<bool> GetDevice(string deviceID)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result;
            string url = Resources.DeviceApi.Get + "?id=" + deviceID;
            result = await App.HttpClientInstance().GetAsync(url);

            if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;


            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        #endregion
    }


public interface IDeviceRegisteredService
{
    Task<bool> GetDevice(string ID);
}
```

I can call the service fine in the browser or though Postman, but when I debug I hit the line

```
result = await App.HttpClientInstance().GetAsync(url);


public static HttpClient _httpClientInstance;
 public static HttpClient HttpClientInstance()
  {
      if (_httpClientInstance == null)
      {
           _httpClientInstance = new HttpClient();
      }

            return _httpClientInstance;
   }
```

and nothing happens, no error or crash but the code just seems to stop.
I guess I'm missing a step here, can anyone point out what I need?

Comment: How is `HttpClientInstance` defined? And what is the url you are using? (Hopefully not "localhost")

Comment: It seems like a deadlock here. Could you please also send us a code snippet of how and where the `GetDevice` method is called?

Comment: I've updated the post to show HttpClientInstance, for test purposes I am using "http://localhost:3000/api/checkdeviceregistered", but like I say, this works fine over the browser